# extract on various lines with logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

so I just discovered logstash and I managed to extract data from log files.
This time, I have to extract information on  MULTIlines, I show you an example:

`2016-03-07 14:09:11,613 INFO  [][com.ole.ecom.jms.crm.JmsCrmSender] Envoi du message ...<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

`<root xmlns="http://wlsosb.gjkjdhdfhkllmld.crm/">`
    `<entry>
        <clients>
            <code>8800356499460</code>
            <raisonsociale>Ole</raisonsociale>
            <siret>51770313800088</siret>
            <civilite>M.</civilite>
            <nom>Aurius</nom>
            <prenom>Gerard</prenom>
            <telephone>0614666644</telephone>
            <email>outiztest+prolivraison@gmail.com</email>
        </clients>`

I have to recover, information on the first line and I must also be able to extract the number in between `<code> 8800356499460 </ code>` and email between the `<email> outiztest+prolivraison@gmail.com </ email >`

if you see how I can do, help me I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to join those lines together, either on the shipper side (filebeat can do this), or with the multiline codec in logstash.